# How to retrieve data after the last Gap in a Sequence

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Is there any function to identify the rows after the last gap (in the below example all highlighted fields) based on the the Column `MET200`.

Need only values from RowNumber 8 onwards.

[image]

Comment: As a rule the `mysql` and `tsql` tags are incompatible, just as the descriptions say. Do you need a solution that works for both? Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below answer.

If you are using `SQL Server T-SQL` then use the below Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE RowNumber>(select MAX(RowNumber) FROM YourTable WHERE len([MET 200])=0)
```

If you are using `MySQL` then use the below Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE RowNumber>(select MAX(RowNumber) FROM YourTable WHERE length([MET 200])=0)
```

Comment: Thank you Dinesh, the concept worked out well  for me .I was able to retrieve the data after the last gap.

Comment: @user5368688, Glad to help you. If you are found this is a right answer, then accept the answer as right. It will help someone search the same issue.